# Generic loop that iterates on both stl map and list (c++)

Tags: c++, templates, stl

Is there any way to write a generic loop whcih iterates over values of both say stl map (associative container) and list (non associateve container).

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T &t)
{
    for (auto iter = t.begin(); iter != t.end(); ++iter)
    {
        printf("%d\n", *iter); // will work for std::list<int> but not for std::map<int, int>
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: They are two different containers. I guess you need to specialize your function template. Chances are you need to rethink / abandon this approach. There already is a [range based loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: You have the generic loop that should work, the only thing is that the *printf()* function in this way will indeed not work. I suggest using *cout* from *c++*, and overload the stream operator to print contents on the screen.

Comment: They have different semantics, what do you want to get from `*iter` if it's a map ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Rotem generic loop that deletes pointer in any collection for example

Comment: @Boris In the case of `map` would you expect it to delete both the key and the value?

Comment: This is not sensical. How is `printf("%d\n", *iter)` supposed to print `std::pair<int,int>`?

Comment: @Rotem values only

Comment: Agree with Stefan. You can't get a generic `printf("%something")`. C is unsuited for generic programming. Just look at the horrible hacks they needed for printing `uint32_t`, and that's just a single type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it work for std::map - use proper [adapter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/map_values.html) from boost:

```
foo(someMap | boost::adaptors::map_values);
```

You might also use Eric Niebler's [ranges-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/test/view/keys_value.cpp)

```
foo(someMap | ranges::values);
```

If you cannot use boost/ranges - use some kind of traits:

```
template <typename ValueType>
struct ValueGetter
{ 
    static Value& get(ValueType& value)
    {
        return value;
    }
};
template <typename Key, typename Value>
struct ValueGetter<std::pair<const Key, Value>>
{ 
    using ValueType = std::pair<const Key, Value>; 
    static Value& get(ValueType& value)
    {
        return value.second;
    }
};

template <typename ValueType>     
auto& getValue(ValueType& value)
{
    return ValueGetter<Value>::get(value);
}

template<typename T>
void foo(T &t)
{
    for (auto iter = t.begin(); iter != t.end(); ++iter)
    {
        printf("%d\n", getValue(*iter)); 
    }

}
```

Comment: You map add that ranges will be added to the C++ standard based on Eric Niebler's https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3.

Comment: @Jens Yes  - I know - I hoped it will in C++17. I'll do.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is already std::for_each (`#include <algorithm>`) for such purposes. You could feed it with appropriate handler, e. g. in the form of a lambda:

```
std::vector<int> v;
std::map<int, double> m;

std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto i) { printf("%d\n", i); });
std::for_each(m.begin(), m.end(), [](auto const& i) { printf("%d %f\n", i.first, i.second); });
```

Answer (score 0):

I do like the way how [Aconcagua](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1312382/aconcagua) show it and in most cases, this would be my favorite choice.

To make it more clear and fill the gap about my comment. The author's loop posted here is ok. In this case, the only problematic thing was about the `printf()`. To solve it, I have suggested something like overloading stream operator() to be able to print out `std::map`

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, pair<string, int> it){
    os << it.first << " => " << it.second;
}
```

as you might have realized the iterator in case of the std::map is the pair. Notice, you do not need to specify that for the `std::list` and the generic loop might look like the following

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T &t){
    for(auto it=t.begin(); it=t.end(); ++it){
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
}
```

which is just fine with what was in the question, except `printf() => cout`. Here, you can also use range-based loops

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T &t){
    for(auto it : t)
        cout << it << endl;
}
```

and finally `for_each()` on the side with functor or lambda expression.